# Javascript/jQuery order of operations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with a line inside an if statement executing before the conditional is met. What I want to do is:

1. Check to see if data (big old array of numbers) is already loaded.
2. If not get it and load it into my all_data object.
3. Plot data (or in this case alert it)

Here's the code (stripped of many details to be readable

```
var all_data={};

function get_data(name,rid) {
    if (!all_data[name]) {
        return $.get('/data.json',
                     {'name':name},
                     function(data) {all_data[name]=data;},
                     "json");
    } else {return true}
}

function load_file(name,rid) {
    if (get_data(name,rid)) { alert(all_data[name]) };
}
```

What happens with the above code is that when I execute get_data it immediately alerts "undefined" because the jQuery.get is returning a (not yet completed) request object. At this point the entry all_data[name] is undefined. If I wait ~5s the get request completes, and running the code again will just alert "[Object Object]" because the data has loaded. I realize I could just put a function in both the $.get callback and it the else statement but that would make this no longer generalized. Any thoughts?

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the stuff that needs to happen whether or not the data is loaded as a callback function to `load_file` itself. This is a *general* solution since if the data is already available your callback is invoked immediately, otherwise it is invoked when the data becomes available.

Also try to eliminate using the global state `all_data` in every function. Limit the scope to local in each function as much as possible.

There are alternate approaches to provide a fluent interface, but without knowing what you're doing with the data after it gets loaded, it is difficult to suggest one.

```
function load_file(name, rid, fn) {
    get_data(name, rid, fn);
}

load_file("..", "..", function() {
    alert(all_data[".."]);
});
```

The `get_data` function then becomes:

```
function get_data(name, rid, fn) {
    if (!all_data[name]) {
        return $.get('/data.json',
                     {'name':name},
                     function(data) { all_data[name]=data; fn(); },
                     "json");
    } else { fn(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the issue is that the $.get() function is asynchronous which immediately returns.  You can use the following the make a synchronous request and it will perform the expected operations.

```
function get_data(name,rid) {
if (!all_data[name]) {
    var result = $.ajax({ async: false,
                 url: '/data.json',
                 data: {'name':name},
                 dataType: "json"
                 });
    all_data[name] = result;

    return result;

} else {return true}
```

}

The "async: false" setting will cause the request to be synchronous and will not continue until receiving a response from the url.